# Routing within sub components with react-navigation 5.x

Tags: react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

There are a few screens in my React Native (0.62) app. Here is the screen structure:

```
--App.js    //NavigationContainer/Stack declared for 2 components : Splashscreen & AppScreen
  --Splashscreen.js
  --AppScreen.js  //AStack declared with 6 components listed below
       --Home.js
         --Upload.js
         --MyFavoritePost.js
             --List.js 
               --Item.js
                 --Itemdetail.js
```

The `List.js`, `Item.js` and `Itemdetail.js` are all under `MyFavoritePost.js`

Here is the `Stack` as declared in `App.js`:

```
<NavigationContainer>
  <Stack.Navigator InitialRouteName="Splash">
    <Stack.Screen name="Splash" component={SplashScreen} options={{headerShown:false}}/>
    <Stack.Screen name="App" component={AppScreen} options={{headerShown:false}} />
  </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

Here is the `AStack` as declared `AppScreen.js`:

```
          <AStack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
            <AStack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
            <AStack.Screen name="Upload" component={Upload} />
            <AStack.Screen name="List" component={Artlist} />
            <AStack.Screen name="MyFavoritePost" component={Newpostfollowed} />
            <AStack.Screen name="Item" component={Imageitem} />
            <AStack.Screen name="ItemDetail" component={Itemdetail} />
          </AStack.Navigator>
```

The declaration of `AStack` seems too excessive as the `List.js` `Item.js` and `Itemdetail.js` are really for presentation of `MyFavoritePost.js`. Does it make sense by declaring `AStack` as 3 components as below:

```
      <AStack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <AStack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
        <AStack.Screen name="Upload" component={Upload} />
        <AStack.Screen name="MyFavoritePost" component={Newpostfollowed} />
      </AStack.Navigator>
```

Within each omponent `Upload` and `MyFacoritePost`, use `navigation.navigate("component")` to route around. The new routing structure becomes:

```
--App.js    //NavigationContainer/Stack declared for 2 components : Splashscreen & AppScreen
  --Splashscreen.js
  --AppScreen.js  //AStack declared with 3 components listed below
       --Home.js
         --Upload.js   //routing with navigation.navigate() within Upload
         --MyFavoritePost.js //routing with navigation.navigate() within MyFavoritePost
             {--List.js 
               --Item.js
                 --Itemdetail.js}  //those 3 components are removed and not to be declared in navigation stack & will route with navigation.navigate()
```

Does the new routing structure make sense? Any problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, the second structure will not work if you remove the three-screen which are under MyFavoritePost component then u cannot use `navigation.navigate()` to go to that screen.
you can do one thing you can create a stack navigator separate for these three screens and use in MyFavoritePost component.
else first structure is perfect.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I am trying to get away from the nested structure as the react-navigation doc https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators advises against it citing performance issue. But all those are from the docs and I dont have life experience with nested structure.

Comment: Yes you are correct so the current structure with all the 6 screens in one stack is perfect. This will not increase the nested structure and solve your purpose.
you will get the ```navigation.navigate()`` in all the screens as well